# Django Model to check if value is unique in model property

Tags: python, django

I have two models: `Header` and `TroopsType`, which is used in `OneToOneField` in `Header`. What I am trying to achieve is to check if `Header`'s name is unique, but not only in `Header`'s name field, but also in `TroopsType`'s one. That's because if you choose some value in `troops_type`, then name field is not required and it should, so to speak, inherit that name from `TroopsType` object to not duplicate values by copying it. Of course, if you keep `troops_type` `NULL`, then `Header`'s name is required. How would you do so?

To clearify my train of thought, I attach my current code which I am trying to modify - currently I just copy the name.

`models.py`:

```
class TroopsType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Header(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, unique=True)
    troops_type = models.OneToOneField(
        TroopsType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    data_type = models.ManyToManyField(DataType)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=(~models.Q(name="")),
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_required_name",
            ),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`admin.py`:

```
class HeaderAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Header
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean(self):
        troops_type = self.cleaned_data["troops_type"]
        if troops_type:
            self.cleaned_data["name"] = troops_type.name
        elif not self.cleaned_data["name"]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("No name or troops type.")
        super().clean()


@admin.register(Header)
class HeaderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = HeaderAdminForm
```

Comment: Clarification question: so you're saying that when you make a new `Header` with `troops_type == None`, it should check `Header.name` to make sure it's not reusing a name from `TroopsType.name`?

Comment: Yes. I mean that the `Header.name` can't be the same as any other `Header`'s `Header.name` and `TroopsType.name` at the same time. But if no `Header` has `troops_type` with `TroopsType.name` that some not used `TroopsType` objects has, it's ok and it should be created.

Comment: Gotcha. You can override the `clean` method in the Header model, do `super().clean()`, and then something like: `if not self.troops_type and TroopsType.objects.filter(name=self.name).exists(): raise ValidationError('name', 'error text')`

Comment: Oh, then we didn't understand each other :D But I get your idea of doing it and that's what I needed: ```if self.name and Header.objects.filter(troops_type__name=self.name).exists(): raise ValidationError("Name already exists (inherited from troops type).") elif (self.troops_type and Header.objects.filter(name=self.troops_type.name).exists()): raise ValidationError("Name already exists.")``` You can post an answer for me to accept it. Thanks.